# I am getting the error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

This error is coming from this line:

> from PIL import ImageTk, Image

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you installed it?

Comment: I tried pip install Pillow on the python but it's giving me an invalid syntax

Comment: What's the error of traceback?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what that means. I am only a beginner so that's why

Comment: It must show you where have an invalid syntax.Edit it in your post.

Comment: pip install Pillow-
It's highlighting the i in install

Comment: Hmmmm..you should install it in your **cmd** instead of ``python interpreter``.

Comment: Do i type the same thing here - "pip install Pillow". When i open command prompt it starts of with "C:\Users\jerin>"

Comment: Yes,that's sure.

Comment: it's saying pip is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Then pip is not installed.  Try `python -m ensurepip` to install pip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PIL first with:

```
python3 -m pip install Pillow
```

Comment: I tried that but it's giving me an "invalid syntax"